# Using firefox is ridiculously slow with users having home directory in NFS. Why?

Tags: linux, firefox

We are using vnc viewer and firefox started being very very slow. Not just loading pages, but also clicking on tabs, opening or closing of tabs/browser, almost every action on firefox is slow.

And when I try it force it do something, it will throw error:

> "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script
>   will complete.

Surprisingly, it shows blazing speed with root. Is it something related to process priority? But, I find no abnormal priority/nice values in process output.

Update1: No slowness is observed for users having local home directories instead of NFS. I have tried to change browser.cache.disk.parent_directory to local directory. But still the issue is there.

Comment: How about when not using vnc?

Comment: you might want to check the permissions of temporary directories. It might be hanging while waiting to write to a temp file. Since `root` can write anywhere, that might be the reason for blazing fast speeds for `root`

Comment: btw, certain applications shouldn't be run as root browser is one of them.

Comment: Hi which temp you were referring..any specific location I need to look at?

Comment: I can't access the server without vnc in X11 mode..I have to bring it to runlevel 5, if I use ILO. I think I can try that once.

Comment: @sjsam Hi, I have tried from ILO, same. it's very slow with normal user accounts.

Comment: Hi, I think it's something to do with the NFS share where the home directories present. I have created a local account with local home directory and it shows no slowness. But surprisingly no slowness with other applications. And issue started suddenly. Doing some more checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try relocating the user Firefox temp directory to /tmp, does that improve performance?  By default the browser cache is stored in ~/.mozilla/.  A browser cache typically contains numerous small files and performance over a network share may be sub-optimal.

Try (temporarily, for a test) disabling the disk cache by entering "about:config" in the address bar (no quotes), and toggling browser.disk.cache.enable to False, then restarting Firefox.  If that provides reasonable performance, you may want to investigate hosting the per-user browser cache directory on a local file system if that is possible.

Proposed use of the --profile switch when launching firefox to allow the setting of a local profile directory.  Appears to have resolved the issue according to the OP.

Comment: I haven't disabled the cache, but i did try setting the browser.cache.parent_directory to local disk. And I could see the change in about:cache. But, that doesn't change anything. It's still very slow. Also to note: it's not just loading the pages that is slow, but also the slowness is there using the firefox itself, clicking on icons etc.

Comment: But one thing is sure, if the home directory of the user is local directory, it gives good performance. Is there any other parameters other than cache, like directory to keep the temporary files needed to run the application etc.?

Comment: firefox --help indicates that there is a "--profile <path>" parameter.   Start with profile at <path>.  You would want to ensure that the parent directory of this location has the appropriate permissions set such that users cannot read each other's profile directories.  Give that a try!

Comment: Hi --profile works perfect thanks :) now, as a permanent fix, I need to check why NFS is having that much huge performance impact with firefox alone, but not any other applications. please add this profile parameter in your answer.